# MongoDB finding specific elements and sorting

Tags: mongodb, sorting, find

This is my data in the collection:

```
{ "installation" : 200278 , 
      "date" : [ 
           { "date" : "2014-12-28" , 
                "values" : [ 
                      { "time" : "2014-12-28 00:15:26" , "value" : 26}, 
                      { "time" : "2014-12-28 00:30:26" , "value" : 15} , 
                      { "time" : "2014-12-28 00:45:26" , "value" : 7} , 
                      { "time" : "2014-12-28 01:00:26" , "value" : 32}
                ]
           }, 
           { "date" : "2014-12-29" , 
                "values" : [ 
                      { "time" : "2014-12-29 00:15:26" , "value" : 26}, 
                      { "time" : "2014-12-29 00:30:26" , "value" : 15} , 
                      { "time" : "2014-12-29 00:45:26" , "value" : 7} , 
                      { "time" : "2014-12-29 01:00:26" , "value" : 32}
                ]
           }
     ]
}, 
{ "installation" : 200312
    ...
```

And I try to query this:

```
db.measure.find({"installation" : 200278 , "date.date" : "2014-12-28"}, 
                {"date.date" : 1 , "_id" : 0})
                .sort({"date.date" : 1})
```

First of all I do not understand why "date.date" does not only return the element with "2014-12-28".
In addition maybe I get sorting wrong but not matter my sign on the 1 it still returns the same order.

Result:

```
{ "date" : [ { "date" : "2014-12-28" }, { "date" : "2014-12-29" } ] }
```

**Clarification**

What I want my query to return is only the element:

{ "date" : "2014-12-28" }

The sorting problem is an extension of my hacking on the Mongo api. And a wondering of how this querying works.

Comment: Seems a little vague as to what you want to sort on. Do you just want the arrays sorted or do you want to sort the documents on the latest array result? That point could be made more clear.

Comment: I want the elements named date inside the the array date sorted.

Comment: I think @Disposer actually posted a solution to do that. But as per my comments, there is a way to do this as you insert the array elements and also to sort the elements permanently. This is why you were asked exactly what it is you really want to do.

Comment: In all fairness your edit is still not really clear. Do you now just want to return simply that "date" element. Or do you want everything that matches beneath it? The now edited response from @BatScream still contains some valid points. If not entirely clear why.

Comment: As I am used to SQL queries. I am new to mongo's way of needing everything explained. Select date.date from measure where installation = 200278 and date.date = 2014-12-18 would return date and not anything else.

Comment: I know SQL solutions does not support embedded documents, but all I'm saying is that I am trying to learn this new way of thinking. What you imply is that I understand the way of document databases before I learn to understand document databases. And that my friend is a logical impossibility.

Comment: If you do not think the "accepted" answer truly solves your question or you have another question to ask then please post another question. Comments are not the place to do this. It is better to fully explain yourself in context of a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to aggregate the result.

When you perform a `sort()` chained with a `find()`, the sort applies to the root documents that were filtered by the `find()` query, and not the array sub documents.

In order to sort array elements, you need to use the aggregation pipeline as below:

```
db.measure.aggregate([
{$match:{"installation" : 200278,"date.date" : "2014-12-28"}},
{$unwind:"$date"},
{$sort:{"date.date":-1}},
{$group:{"_id":"$id","installation":{$first:"$installation"},"date":{$push:"$date"}}},
{$project:{"_id" : 0,"installation":1,"date.date":1}}
])
```

> *First of all I do not understand why "date.date" does not only return the element with "2014-12-28".*

To get only the first array element that matches the query, you need to use the [$](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#definition)(positional operator).

```
db.measure.find({"installation" : 200278 , 
                 "date.date" : "2014-12-28"}, 
                 {"date.$" : 1,"_id":0})
```

If you wish to keep the `date` array always sorted by `date`, you could ensure that while making updates to the array, by making use of the `$each` and `$sort` update operators.

```
db.measures.update({"installation":200278},
            {$push:{
                    date:{
                          $each:[{date object},
                                 {date object},...],
                          $sort:{"date":-1}, // sort the date array by `date` 
                                             // field during updates
                         }
            }})
```

So a find query would always return a sorted array of date documents for each installation.

Comment: The approach with `.aggregate()` is all fine. But new users could possibly have better clarifications on their real problems. As above. +1 for the effort but I'm not sure this solves the real problem without asking.

Comment: Actually i am in process of replying with why the code doesn't work as OP expects it to.

Comment: Actually there is no response from the OP or any further explanation of what they are doing or whether aggregation and sorting of the array post "record" is the right way to do so. Hence the comment, hence "you could have asked", hence the general. It's not an "attack" just something to consider when the overall objective seems vague (IMHO).

Comment: Yes its fine Neil, i understand. Should have asked for a clarification before posting. Will do that the next time. I simply assumed what the OP was trying to ask in this case.

Comment: You can always posy the alternate case for ordering the array as it is modified. Still does not clear up exactly what they wish to sort on but at least it sorts that out. I can only vote once, but others might appreciate the different perspectives.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of the positional operator. That solved my find query problem. 
I find the aggregation method very complicated to understand. But I suppose subdocuments makes things complex to start with.

Comment: @miniwolf - Its fine. You need to look into aggregation solutions to solve problems involving sub documents. The beginning is always a bit tough for whatever you learn.

Comment: In the aggregate example. How would you extend this so it would only return the element matching the date? Now we return all dates, but how do I make it return only "installation" : 200278, "date" : [ { "date" : "2014-12-28" } ] }"

Answer (score 0):

A beautified solution for completeness with help from our own @BatScream

```
db.measure.aggregate([ {$match:{ "installation" : 200278}}, 
                       {$unwind:"$date"}, 
                       {$match:{"date.date":"2014-12-28"}}, 
                       {$project:{"_id" : 0,"date.date":1, "date.values":1}} 
                    ])
```

Result:

```
{ date" : { "date" : "2014-12-28", "values" : [ 
             { "time" : "2014-12-28 00:15:26", "value" : 26 }, 
             { "time" : "2014-12-28 00:30:26", "value" : 15 }, 
             { "time" : "2014-12-28 00:45:26", "value" : 7 }, 
             { "time" : "2014-12-28 01:00:26", "value" : 32 } 
             ]
         } }
```