# Querying mongodb collection with subdocument array in sorted order

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I've following model structure:

```
Public Class WorksheetModel
{
 [BsonId]
 [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
 public string Id { get; set; }

 public string WSName {get; set;}

 public string UserId {get; set;}

 public List<QuizModel> Quiz { get; set; } 
}

Public Class QuizModel
{
 [BsonId]
 [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
 public string Id { get; set; }

 public string QuizName {get; set;}
}
```

when I save, it produces structure in db something like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54a4e902bb63bc1370aff4a7"),
    "WSName" : "WS2",
    "UserId" : "54a4e902bb63bc1370aff5b9",
    "Quiz" : [
     {
      "_id" : null,
      "QuizName " : "Qz2"
     },
     {
      "_id" : null,
      "QuizName " : "Qz1"
     },
     {
      "_id" : null,
      "QuizName " : "Qz2"
     },
    ]
},
```

I use following query to get worksheets list ordered by "WSName"

```
_collection = _db.GetCollection<WorksheetModel>("Worksheets");
_query = Query<WorksheetModel>.Where( e => e.UserId == oModel.UserId);
_cursor = _collection.Find(_query).SetSortOrder(SortBy.Ascending("WSName"));
```

But now I want to retrieve worksheets list in such a way where the subdocument array **Quiz** should also be **ordered by QuizName**.

The final result should look like this:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("54a4e902bb63bc1370aff4a7"),
        "WSName" : "WS1",
        "UserId" : "54a4e902bb63bc1370aff5b9",
        "Quiz" : [
         {
          "_id" : null,
          "QuizName " : "Qz1"
         },
         {
          "_id" : null,
          "QuizName " : "Qz2"
         },
         {
          "_id" : null,
          "QuizName " : "Qz2"
         },
        ]
    },
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("54a4e902bb63bc1370aff4a7"),
        "WSName" : "WS2",
        "UserId" : "54a4e902bb63bc1370aff5b9",
        "Quiz" : [
         {
          "_id" : null,
          "QuizName " : "Qz4"
         },
         {
          "_id" : null,
          "QuizName " : "Qz4"
         },
         {
          "_id" : null,
          "QuizName " : "Qz5"
         },
        ]
    },
```

Now how should I query the document from C# so that I'll get above result.

Comment: You can always sort the documents at the root level when retrieving. But you cannot sort array elements when you do a `find()`, simply because it then becomes manipulation of the document data. To manipulate the order of the array elements, i.e order them, you can follow two approaches - either perform an aggregation operation or store the array elements in sorted order during inserts and updates. One such use case has been addressed here, though not in c#, which may be helpful. - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27686722/mongodb-finding-specific-elements-and-sorting/27687159#27687159.

Comment: you can write a custom serializer for WorksheetModel, and when it deserialize your document, you can sort embedded array in your deserilize method